# how can i get value of moment format date picker in format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, momentjs, antd

i've a vue apps containing datepicker by ant-design-vue that return

```
Moment {…}
_d: Thu Oct 24 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DD"
_i: "1996-10-15"
_isAMomentObject: (...)
_isUTC: (...)
_isValid: (...)
_locale: (...)
_pf: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: Moment, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get _d: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _d: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _f: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _f: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _i: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _i: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _isAMomentObject: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _isAMomentObject: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _isUTC: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _isUTC: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _isValid: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _isValid: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _locale: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _locale: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get _pf: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set _pf: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

where i need the date format in `YYYY-MM-DD`

it's succeed when get straight from onChange event with this code.

```
function(date = moment, dateString) {
      if (date) {
        console.log(dateString)
}
```

but in my project, i'm using v-decorator where gets all data through the form.
this is my script where i've tried calling the date:

```
this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
          console.log(values.birthday);
)}
```

this is my datepicker structure:

```
<a-form-item v-bind="formItemLayout" label="Date Of Birth">
    <a-date-picker
     v-decorator="[ 'birthday',
      {
       initialValue: moment(profile.birthday),
        rules: [{required: true, message: 'Date Of Birth is required.'}]
      },
     ]"
       @change="handleAge"
       format="DD/MM/YYYY"
      style="width:120px;"
      />
     </a-form-item>
```

and it's return the above moment. how can i get only YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: I don't understand where you are getting the data from and what method you are using

Comment: Try format='YYYY-MM-DD'.  Ref: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this below?  It

> For initial Rendering 
>   initialValue: moment(profile.birthday).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

```
<a-form-item v-bind="formItemLayout" label="Date Of Birth">
<a-date-picker
 v-decorator="[ 'birthday',
  {
    rules: [{required: true, message: 'Date Of Birth is required.'}],
    initialValue: moment(profile.birthday).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  },
 ]"
   @change="handleAge"
   format="DD/MM/YYYY"
  style="width:120px;"
  />
 </a-form-item>
```

> For Submission:

```
this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
     let birthday = moment(values.birthday).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

          console.log(birthday);
)}
```

Let me know if it works for you and should you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In ant-design, the `Datepicke`r by default returns the moment object as the value so I used some logics to return only the Date value from the moment object. This is how you can return date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

create a function to change the moment object to return the only Date in  `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Here's how you do in your project:

```js
const convert = (str) => {
    var date = new Date(str),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
  };
```

```js
this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
    console.log(convert(values.birthday));
)}
```